# Duplicate entry in ElasticSearch despite aggragation in Logstash

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a dump of the IMDB database in form of a CSV.
The CSV look like this :

```
name, movie, role
"'El Burro' Van Rankin, Jorge","Serafín (1999)",PLAYED_IN
"'El Burro' Van Rankin, Jorge","Serafín (1999)",PLAYED_IN
"'El Burro' Van Rankin, Jorge","Serafín (1999)",PLAYED_IN
.........
"A.S., Alwi","Rumah masa depan (1984)",PLAYED_IN
"A.S., Giri","Sumangali (1940)",PLAYED_IN
"A.S., Luis","Bob the Drag Queen: Bloodbath (2016)",PLAYED_IN
"A.S., Pragathi","Suli (2016)",PLAYED_IN
"A.S.F. Dancers, The","D' Lucky Ones! (2006)",PLAYED_IN
.........
```

My goal is to put the data in Elastic Search but I don't want to have duplicate of actors so I want to aggregate the movie they are playing in so that the dataset look like this :

```
{
    "_index": "imdb13",
    "_type": "logs",
    "_id": "AVmw9JHCrsOFTsZwAmBm",
    "_score": 13.028783,
    "_source": {
      "@timestamp": "2017-01-18T09:42:15.149Z",
      "movie": [
        "Naomi and Ely's No Kiss List (2015)",
        "Staten Island Summer (2015/II)",
        "What Happened Last Night (2016)",
        ...
      ],
      "@version": "1",
      "name": "Abernethy, Kevin",
    }
  }
```

So I am using Logstash to push the data into ElasticSearch. I use the aggregate plugin and my configuration file is the following :

```
input {  
        file {
             path => "/home/maeln/imdb-data/roles.csv"
             start_position => "beginning"
        }
}

filter {  
        csv {
            columns => [ "name", "movie" ]
            remove_field => ["role", "message", "host", "column3", "path"]
            separator => ","
        }

        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{name}"
            code => "
                map['movie'] ||= []
                    event.to_hash.each do |key,value|
                    map[key] = value unless map.has_key?(key)
                    map[key] << value if map[key].is_a?(Array)
                end
                "
            push_previous_map_as_event => true
            timeout => 30
            timeout_tags => ['aggregated']
        }

        if "aggregated" not in [tags] {
            drop {}
        }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "imdb13"
    }
}
```

But then, when I do a simple search on the index, all the actors are duplicated with only one movie in the "movie" field, like this :

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 149,
    "max_score": 13.028783,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "imdb13",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "AVmw9JHCrsOFTsZwAmBm",
        "_score": 13.028783,
        "_source": {
          "@timestamp": "2017-01-18T09:42:15.149Z",
          "movie": [
            "Naomi and Ely's No Kiss List (2015)"
          ],
          "@version": "1",
          "name": "Abernethy, Kevin",
          "tags": [
            "aggregated"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "imdb13",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "AVmw9JHCrsOFTsZwAmBq",
        "_score": 12.998644,
        "_source": {
          "@timestamp": "2017-01-18T09:42:15.149Z",
          "movie": [
            "Staten Island Summer (2015/II)"
          ],
          "@version": "1",
          "name": "Abernethy, Kevin",
          "tags": [
            "aggregated"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "imdb13",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "AVmw9JHCrsOFTsZwAmBu",
        "_score": 12.998644,
        "_source": {
          "@timestamp": "2017-01-18T09:42:15.150Z",
          "movie": [
            "What Happened Last Night (2016)"
          ],
          "@version": "1",
          "name": "Abernethy, Kevin",
          "tags": [
            "aggregated"
          ]
        }
      },
      .....
```

Is there a way to fix this ?

The log from logstash with the --debug option (only partially, the whole log is around ~1Gio) : [paste](http://pastebin.com/aZtRLmzm) (I put it on pastebin because of the 30000 chars limit in stackoverflow).

The last lines of the log :

```
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,977][DEBUG][logstash.filters.csv     ] filters/LogStash::Filters::CSV: removing field {:field=>"path"}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,977][DEBUG][logstash.filters.csv     ] filters/LogStash::Filters::CSV: removing field {:field=>"role"}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,977][DEBUG][logstash.filters.csv     ] Event after csv filter {:event=>2017-01-18T10:34:09.900Z %{host} %{message}}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,977][DEBUG][logstash.filters.csv     ] filters/LogStash::Filters::CSV: removing field {:field=>"message"}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,977][DEBUG][logstash.filters.csv     ] filters/LogStash::Filters::CSV: removing field {:field=>"path"}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,977][DEBUG][logstash.filters.csv     ] filters/LogStash::Filters::CSV: removing field {:field=>"host"}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,977][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2017-01-18T10:34:09.897Z, "movie"=>["Tayong dalawa (2009)"], "@version"=>"1", "name"=>"Anselmuccio, Alex", "tags"=>["aggregated"]}}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,977][DEBUG][logstash.filters.csv     ] Event after csv filter {:event=>2017-01-18T10:34:09.915Z %{host} %{message}}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,977][DEBUG][logstash.filters.csv     ] filters/LogStash::Filters::CSV: removing field {:field=>"column3"}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,977][DEBUG][logstash.filters.aggregate] Aggregate create_timeout_event call with task_id 'Anson, Christopher'
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,977][DEBUG][logstash.filters.csv     ] filters/LogStash::Filters::CSV: removing field {:field=>"path"}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,977][DEBUG][logstash.util.decorators ] filters/LogStash::Filters::Aggregate: adding tag {"tag"=>"aggregated"}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,977][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2017-01-18T10:34:09.917Z, "movie"=>["Tabi tabi po! (2001)"], "@version"=>"1", "name"=>"Anson, Alvin", "tags"=>["aggregated"]}}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.filters.csv     ] Event after csv filter {:event=>2017-01-18T10:34:09.921Z %{host} %{message}}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.filters.aggregate] Aggregate successful filter code execution {:code=>"\n\t\t\t\tmap['movie'] ||= []\n\t\t\t\t\tevent.to_hash.each do |key,value|\n\t\t\t\t\tmap[key] = value unless map.has_key?(key)\n\t\t\t\t\tmap[key] << value if map[key].is_a?(Array)\n\t\t\t\tend\n\t\t\t\t"}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2017-01-18T10:34:09.911Z, "movie"=>["21 Jump Street (1987)"], "@version"=>"1", "name"=>"Ansley, Zachary", "tags"=>["aggregated"]}}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.filters.aggregate] Aggregate create_timeout_event call with task_id 'Anseth, Elias Moussaoui'
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2017-01-18T10:34:09.897Z, "movie"=>["Tayong dalawa (2009)"], "@version"=>"1", "name"=>"Anselmuccio, Alex", "tags"=>["aggregated"]}}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.util.decorators ] filters/LogStash::Filters::Aggregate: adding tag {"tag"=>"aggregated"}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2017-01-18T10:34:09.917Z, "movie"=>["The Death Match: Fighting Fist of Samurai Joe (2013)"], "@version"=>"1", "name"=>"Anson, Alvin", "tags"=>["aggregated"]}}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.filters.aggregate] Aggregate successful filter code execution {:code=>"\n\t\t\t\tmap['movie'] ||= []\n\t\t\t\t\tevent.to_hash.each do |key,value|\n\t\t\t\t\tmap[key] = value unless map.has_key?(key)\n\t\t\t\t\tmap[key] << value if map[key].is_a?(Array)\n\t\t\t\tend\n\t\t\t\t"}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2017-01-18T10:34:09.917Z, "movie"=>["The Diplomat Hotel (2013)"], "@version"=>"1", "name"=>"Anson, Alvin", "tags"=>["aggregated"]}}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.filters.aggregate] Aggregate create_timeout_event call with task_id 'Anson, Alvin'
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2017-01-18T10:34:09.897Z, "movie"=>["Tayong dalawa (2009)"], "@version"=>"1", "name"=>"Anselmuccio, Alex", "tags"=>["aggregated"]}}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] filter received {"event"=>{"path"=>"/home/maeln/Projets/oracle-of-bacon/imdb-data/roles.csv", "@timestamp"=>2017-01-18T10:34:09.900Z, "@version"=>"1", "host"=>"maeln-GE70-2PE", "message"=>"\"Ansfelt, Jacob\",\"Manden med de gyldne ører (2009)\",PLAYED_IN"}}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.util.decorators ] filters/LogStash::Filters::Aggregate: adding tag {"tag"=>"aggregated"}
[2017-01-18T11:34:09,978][DEBUG][logstash.filters.aggregate] Aggregate successful filter code execution {:code=>"\n\t\t\t\tmap['movie'] ||= []\n\t\t\t\t\tevent.to_hash.each do |key,value|\n\t\t\t\t\tmap[key] = value unless map.has_key?(key)\n\t\t\t\t\tmap[key] << value if map[key].is_a?(Array)\n\t\t\t\tend\n\t\t\t\t"}
```

Pastebin with only the line containing logstash.filters.aggregate : [link](http://pastebin.com/BVptgkpX)

Comment: Can you add the `--debug` flag on the command line and update your question with the output you get?

Comment: @Val Done, but the log are huge so I only put a partial one.

Comment: Can you grep only the lines having `logstash.filters.aggregate` ?

Comment: @Val I added it in the question.

Comment: If you check that log file, you'll see that `$lim, Bee Moe` comes a few times but it's always preceded by another name, so a new event is created each time... Are you sure that your input file is properly sorted by name? The way you've chosen to do it, all names must be sorted prior to running this.

Comment: I have check with `Abernethy, Kevin` and `$lim, Bee Moe` and they are properly sorted. I have no guarantee that the file is perfectly sorted for every actors but I certainly seem so and. Would having just one actor unsorted screw up the processing for the others ?

Comment: I think the issue you're facing relates to the fact that once a line is read it is handed out to a filter+output thread. If you have several CPUs, several of those threads will be processing your lines in parallel and hence the output order is not guaranteed anymore. More importantly, each of your `aggregate` filter will be local to a given thread so it's definitely possible that several lines relating to the same actor (in order) get processed by different threads in parallel. That would explain.

Comment: I have try with option `-w 1` in logstash and adding `workers => 1` in the output elasticsearch part of the conf file and it's working :) !
Thank you, can you answer the question so I can validate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing relates to the fact that once a line is read it is handed out to a filter+output thread.

If you have several CPUs, several of those threads will be processing your lines in parallel and hence the output order is not guaranteed anymore. More importantly, each of your `aggregate` filters will be local to a given thread so it's definitely possible that several lines relating to the same actor (even if in order) get processed by different threads in parallel and the output order might differ.

Once solution would be to run logstash with the option `-w 1` to only create a single worker thread, but you'll decrease the throughput by doing so.